# Match all digits but not string

Tags: search

I'm trying to find a pattern that will match for any digits, except ":3"

I've tried this

```
/\v(:3)@!&\d
```

But it doesn't work and I've no idea why

Comment: Does it have to be colon-3? Colon isnt a digit, so i would use [012456789]*

Comment: Please provide more info -- example text and what should be matched in that text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match all digits if there is no `:` before them

```
/\v:@<!\d
```

Add all digits except 3

```
/\v:@<!\d|[0124-9]
```

[image: Results of the last regexp]